# Check that a byte array is an image

Tags: go

I have a server endpoint in gin that receives an byte array.

```
func UploadImageHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    body, err := c.GetRawData()

    // how do I make sure this body byte array is image?
}
```

I need to ensure that the byte array is an image.

How would I be able to do this check in Go?

Comment: Try to decode is as an image, and see if there are any errors

Comment: @BurakSerdar Do you have an example of that? I think it will work, i'll mark your answer accepted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this : https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode

You will end up with :

```
func UploadImageHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    body, err := c.GetRawData()

    img, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
    ....
}
```

I have not tested though.